# Suggested DB Schema for Quotes

Tags: mysql, database-design, serialization, schema

How would you save the quote products in a database? Serialize data?

http://cl.ly/6419969e30cd26e2f32a

They can create however many rows they want... It's for a quote system. Create a quote with however many products. I need to save X Product At X Qty and X Price foreach one.

Serialize in the only thing I could come up with, but I hate unserializing so very much. I didn't know if there was a quicker/more efficient way.

I also have all this information to store with / link with it http://cl.ly/40cc9fea47932b3740b2

PHP (Kohana) > mySQL

Thanks for any input you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the items on a quote into a separate child table:

```
Quote           QuoteItem        Item
=========       ===========      ============
QuoteID         QuoteID          ItemID
Subject         ItemID           Description      
ValidUntil      Quantity         Cost
Address         Price
```

Create one entry in the quote table, and then for each item on that quote create an entry in the QuoteItem table with the corresponding QuoteID.

Comment: I appreciate your input. That was my preferred route, however I wasn't sure that was most optimal... I'm thinking for my program layout that that would be the best option.

Comment: This is the properly normalised way to implement it. You have a many-to-many relationship between `Quote` and `Item` since one item can appear on many quotes, and one quote can contain many items. Therefore you need a junction table (QuoteItem) to join the two.